# About covers, subcovers and compactness

Tags: general-topology

I have a doubt about covers, finite subcovers and its relation with compactness.

Let $X$ be a topological space. We define an open cover of $A\subset X$ as an union of a collection of open subsets of $X$ that **contains** $A$.

We define a finite subcover taking a finite number of those sets that still cover $A$.

If a set has a finite open subcover, then it's compact.

> **Question:** $(-1,0)\cup(-1/2,2)$ is a finite open cover of $(0,1)$. Regarding the definition of compactness, $(0,1)$ is compact. What am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: For a set $A$ to be compact you must be able to take any collection of open sets $\{U_i: i\in I\}$ ($I$ is an arbitrary index set) such that $A\subset \cup_i U_i$ and then out of *these* arbitrary $U_i$ you must find finitely many that still do the job of covering $A$—it isn’t enough to find any finite subcover, you must extract one from the original arbitrary open cover

Comment: Just to give a concrete example, consider the cover $\{(0,a): 0<a<1\}$ of $(0,1)$. If there was a finite subcover, then it would have the form $\{(0,a_1),\dots,(0,a_n)\}$ where we can impose the order $a_1<\dots<a_n$, and thus the union of these sets is $(0,a_n)$. But $a_n<1$, so $(0,a_n)$ is a *proper* subset of $(0,1)$ and does not cover it. Thus no finite cover can exist, and so $(0,1)$ is not compact.

Comment: "If a set has a finite open subcover, then it's compact."  No.  It's not the *set* that has the subcover.  It is the open cover that has the finite subcover.  A set is compact if *every* open cover has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of compactness is wrong. A subset $A\subset X$ is compact if, given any open cover of that set, we can extract a finite open subcover. That is, to check compactness of $A$, you have to take an arbitrary collection $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of open sets that cover $A$ and prove that you find finitely many $i_1,\dots,i_n\in I$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n U_{i_k}$. By your definition, every subset would be compact since it can be covered by $X$ itself.

Comment: A *finite* open subcover.

Comment: okay, so let's take $(-3,0)\cup (-1,0)\cup(-1/2,2)$ as a cover of $(0,1)$. Then we take the subcover in my question. It means that $(0,1)$ is compact?

Comment: @Alure No, you cannot just choose an open cover of your liking, you have to show that it works for any open cover.

Comment: @Alure you are still missing the fact that to prove this directly you need to start with an *arbitrary* open cover. One you know nothing about.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: *however* to show that $(0,1)$ *isn’t* compact you can pick any open cover you want and show any finite subcover of it must fail. You are being tripped up by the quantifiers in the definitions.

Comment: Okay, so that's the point, that's what I was looking for. Thank you @LoveTooNap29.

Comment: @Alure actually let me clarify one more thing, you should always start with infinite open covers, whether youre proving compactness or showing it is not compact. In the latter case, you may choose which one to work with.

Answer (score 2):

"If a set has a finite open subcover, then it's compact."

This is incorrect.

The correct definition is "If *every* open cover of a set, has a finite subcover, then the set is compact."

"(−1,0)∪(−1/2,2) is a finite open cover of (0,1)"

Right, but so what?

it is not the *only* open cover of $(0,1)$.  For $(0,1)$ to be compact.  *Every* open cover has a finite subcover.  The is only one open cover.  There are others and if $(0,1)$ is not compact, at least one open cover will not have an open cover.  But if *every* possible open cover, *any* open cover anyone in the universe can think of has a finite subcover, then $(0,1)$ is compact.

Suppose I said:  A country is "rich" if every single person has over \$500,000.  And the I said: America is not rich because not every single person has over \$500,000.  And you said: What about Malcolm Forbes?  He has over \$500,000.  So isn't America a "rich" country.  The answer to that is Malcolm Forbes is not every single person.  To be "rich" *everyone* must have more than \$500,000.

So the question comes down to: Can we think of an open cover of $(0,1)$ that has no finite subcover?

In the comment Santana Afton had a good example of an open cover of $(0,1)$ that has no finite subcover.

Let $0 < a < 1$ and let $U_a = (0,a)$.  I claim that $\{U_a|a \in (0,1)\} = \{ (0,a)|0 < a < 1\}$ is an open cover.

Pf:  If $x \in (0,1)$ then there is a $y$ so that $0 < x < y < 1$ so $x \in (0,y)= U_y$.  So $x$ is "covered" by $\{U_a\}$. That is true for all $x$ so all of $(0,1)$ is covered.  And as $(0,a)$ is open it is an open cover.

I claim it has no finite subset that covers $(0,1)$. If there is a finite subset  $\{(0, a_n)\}$ for some finite number of $a_i$ then there is a maximum value of $A = \max (a_i)$ so $a_i \le A < 1$ for all $\{(0,a_n)\} $.  So if $A < x < 1$ then $x \not \in (0, a_i)$ for any of the finite number of $a_i$.  So $x$ is *not* covered by $\{(0, a_n)\}$.

So no finite subset of $\{(0,a)\}$ will cover $(0,1)$.  So $\{(0,a)\}$ has no finite subcover.

So $(0,1)$ is not compact.